# How I can split my array to multiple arrays based in a value with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, split, indexof

I have an array and I want to split it to multiple arrays based on the value 'Finished', when I find it, I split the array.

My code is :

```js
var input = ['urlGettingF', '├─BROKEN─aquaHTTP_404', '├─BROKEN─url1HTTP_404' , 'ok', 'urlok', 'Finished', 
            'urlGettingF2', '├─BROKEN─url1HTTP_404','├─BROKEN─url21HTTP_404', 'Finished',
            'urlGettingF3', '├─BROKEN─url3HTTP_404','├─BROKEN─url213HTTP_404', 'Finished'
];

function chunkArray(array, size) {
  let result = []
  for (value of array) {
    let lastArray = result[result.length - 1]
    if (!lastArray || lastArray.length == size) {
      result.push([value])
    } else {
      lastArray.push(value)
    }
  }
  return result
}

const x = input.findIndex(element => element.indexOf('Finished') > -1)
console.log(chunkArray(input, x + 1));
```

when I run it I get :

[image]

But I want the result will be :

```
[["urlGettingF", "├─BROKEN─aquaHTTP_404", "├─BROKEN─url1HTTP_404", "ok", "urlok", "Finished"], ["urlGettingF2", "├─BROKEN─url1HTTP_404", "├─BROKEN─url21HTTP_404", "Finished"], ["urlGettingF3", "├─BROKEN─url3HTTP_404", "├─BROKEN─url213HTTP_404", "Finished"]]
```

When I find `Finished`, I split my array based on her index, you can see my code in jsbin
https://jsbin.com/benozuyutu/1/edit?js,console

How I can fix it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var input = ['urlGettingF', '├─BROKEN─aquaHTTP_404', '├─BROKEN─url1HTTP_404', 'ok', 'urlok', 'Finished',
  'urlGettingF2', '├─BROKEN─url1HTTP_404', '├─BROKEN─url21HTTP_404', 'Finished',
  'urlGettingF3', '├─BROKEN─url3HTTP_404', '├─BROKEN─url213HTTP_404', 'Finished'
];

function chunkArray(arr) {
  let result = [
    []
  ];
  let index = 0;
  arr.forEach((x, i) => {
    result[index].push(x);
    if ((i + 1) < arr.length && x.includes('Finished')) {
      index++;
      result[index] = [];
    }
  });
  return result
}
console.log(chunkArray(input));
```

Answer (score 2):

You might find all occurrences of `Finished` with `.reduce`, then create a new array by `.slice`ing each occurrence at the found indicies:

```js
var input = ['urlGettingF', '├─BROKEN─aquaHTTP_404', '├─BROKEN─url1HTTP_404', 'ok', 'urlok', 'Finished',
  'urlGettingF2', '├─BROKEN─url1HTTP_404', '├─BROKEN─url21HTTP_404', 'Finished',
  'urlGettingF3', '├─BROKEN─url3HTTP_404', '├─BROKEN─url213HTTP_404', 'Finished'
];

const finishedIndicies = input.reduce((a, item, i) => {
  if (item === 'Finished') {
    a.push(i);
  }
  return a;
}, []);
const chunked = finishedIndicies.map(
  (sliceIndex, i, arr) => input.slice(arr[i - 1] === undefined ? 0 : arr[i - 1] + 1, sliceIndex + 1)
);
console.log(chunked);
```

Comment: `.reduce` can be replaced with a simple `for` loop. `.reduce` reduces the code readability.

Comment: @AdityaBhave Opinion-based, but I prefer `reduce` because it *is* an appropriate tool for transforming an array into a single accumulator, when that accumulator isn't one-to-one- with the input array

Comment: @CertainPerformance yes.. I agree that it is opinion based. Check this youtube video from Surma and Jake https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qaGjS7-qWzg

Answer (score 2):

```js
var input = ['urlGettingF', '├─BROKEN─aquaHTTP_404', '├─BROKEN─url1HTTP_404', 'ok', 'urlok', 'Finished', 'urlGettingF2', '├─BROKEN─url1HTTP_404', '├─BROKEN─url21HTTP_404', 'Finished', 'urlGettingF3', '├─BROKEN─url3HTTP_404', '├─BROKEN─url213HTTP_404', 'Finished']

const res = input
  .join(' ')
  .split('Finished')
  .map(item => item.split(' ').filter(item => item))
  .filter(item => item.length)
  .map(item => [...item, 'Finished'])
 
console.log(res)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use following algorithm.

1. Find `indexOf('Finished')`
2. Use `Array.splice` function to get the values till the `index`. `.splice` also updates the existing Array.
3. Do above until `indexOf('Finished') > -1`
4. Finally, add the remaining `input array` in the `output array`

```js
let input = ['urlGettingF', '├─BROKEN─aquaHTTP_404', '├─BROKEN─url1HTTP_404', 'ok', 'urlok', 'Finished',
  'urlGettingF2', '├─BROKEN─url1HTTP_404', '├─BROKEN─url21HTTP_404', 'Finished',
  'urlGettingF3', '├─BROKEN─url3HTTP_404', '├─BROKEN─url213HTTP_404', 'Finished'
];

let output = [];

while (true) {
  output.push(input.splice(0, input.indexOf('Finished') + 1));

  if (input.indexOf('Finished') === -1) {
    input.length && output.push(input); //to add all remaining values
    
    break;
  }
}

console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `reduce` method. In `reduce` method, it is necessary to check whether keyword to find exists and if exists push into newly created array. Otherwise, we are pushing into existing array:

```
let keywordToFind = 'urlGettingF';

const result = input.reduce((a, c) => {
    (c.includes(keywordToFind)) ? a.push([c]) : a[a.length - 1].push(c); 
    return a;
}, []);
```

An example:

```js
var input = ['urlGettingF', '├─BROKEN─aquaHTTP_404', 
   '├─BROKEN─url1HTTP_404', 'ok', 'urlok', 'Finished',
  'urlGettingF2', '├─BROKEN─url1HTTP_404', '├─BROKEN─url21HTTP_404', 'Finished',
  'urlGettingF3', '├─BROKEN─url3HTTP_404', '├─BROKEN─url213HTTP_404', 'Finished'
];


let keywordToFind = 'urlGettingF';
const result = input.reduce((a, c) => {
    (c.includes(keywordToFind)) ? a.push([c]) : a[a.length - 1].push(c);
    return a;
}, []);

console.log(result);
```